# PHP not so fatal errors with "new SoapClient()"

Tags: php, soap-client

I have this snippet running:

```
foreach($config as $wsInfo){
  try{
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsInfo['url'], 
                                 array('encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1'));

    //  Some more code that I commented out.

  }
  catch(Exception $e){
    echo "EXCEPTION: \n" . $e->getMessage();
    // log it, etc.
  }
}
```

When I run the program the Web Service URL responds me with an authentication error (which is ok at this point of development).

The extrange behavior I'm noting is that, while I was expecting for this:

```
$ php scan.php -p=/ -c=config.yml
EXCEPTION: 
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://webservices.myserver.com/api.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://webservices.myserver.com/api.asmx?WSDL"
EXCEPTION: 
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://webservices.myserver.com/api.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://webservices.myserver.com/api.asmx?WSDL"
```

It's giving me this:

```
$ php scan.php -p=/ -c=config.yml
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://webservices.myserver.com/api.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://webservices.myserver.com/api.asmx?WSDL"
 in /home/me/project/DFPushSOAP.php on line 34
EXCEPTION: 
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://webservices.myserver.com/api.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://webservices.myserver.com/api.asmx?WSDL"
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://webservices.myserver.com/api.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://webservices.myserver.com/api.asmx?WSDL"
 in /home/me/project/DFPushSOAP.php on line 34
EXCEPTION: 
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://webservices.myserver.com/api.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://webservices.myserver.com/api.asmx?WSDL"
```

Why is a "PHP Fatal error" not killing the program? And why is it escaping the try/catch block?

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a solution at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47584.

At first you should set `exceptions` options to force SoapClient to throw Exceptions:

```
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsInfo['url'], array('encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1'
                                                       'exceptions' => true ));
```

in my case xdebug was forcing to produce a Fatal Error instead of a catchable Exception.
So you should try to disable xdebug for the SoapClient creation:

```
    if(function_exists('xdebug_disable')){ xdebug_disable(); };
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsInfo['url'], array('encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1'
                                                       'exceptions' => true ));
    if(function_exists('xdebug_enable')){ xdebug_enable(); };
```

hope this will help you ^^

Answer (score 0):

The solution with temporarily disabling xdebug does not work for me (running *PHP 7.0.12 / amd64)* with enabled xdebug).

The answers the mentioned bug at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47584 show a solution with an custom temporary error handler. See post from _ [2012-10-03 09:36 UTC] james dot silver at computerminds dot co dot uk_.

As a dirty workaround you can deactivate `error_reporting()`

```
$level = error_reporting();
error_reporting(0);
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsInfo['url'], array(
    'encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1'
    'exceptions' => true )
);
error_reporting($level);
```

But the custom error handler looks more pleasant. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12565073/4351778