# PHP - SOAP "Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from ..." Error

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

This is my code:

```
$this->options = [
    "login" => $username,
    "password" => $password
];
try {
    $this->request = new SoapClient('https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsesya?wsdl', $this->options);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
}
```

And this is the error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsesya?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsesya?wsdl"

Any idea how I can fix this error?

[UPDATE]

I can get functions with this code:

```
$wsdl = file_get_contents('https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsesya?wsdl');
```

But this code still gets error:

```
SoapClient('https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsesya?wsdl', $this->options);
```

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690722/fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-wsdl-coul

Comment: @maniksidana unfortunately this solution not working for me

Answer (score 0):

try  from command line:

```
wget https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsesya?wsdl
```

or

```
php -r '$a = new SoapClient("https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsesya?wsdl"); var_dump($a);'
```

Maybe resource id not available from tour host

Comment: I received this message:
`object(SoapClient)#1 (2) {
  ["_soap_version"]=>
  int(1)
  ["sdl"]=>
  resource(5) of type (SOAP SDL)
}`

Answer (score 0):

To handle SOAP exceptions, you can give this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952814/php-soap-error-catching/16394213) a try. Following code is standalone code which is returning a SOAP response.

```
 $params = array(
    "login" => "USERNAME",
    "password" => "PASSWORD"
);
try {
    $client = new SoapClient('https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsesya?wsdl', array($params));
} catch(Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
}
```

To List all available SOAP functions:

```
echo " List of available SOAP functions <br/><pre>"; var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); echo "</pre>";
```

To List all available SOAP types:

```
echo "List of SOAP types <br/><pre>"; var_dump($client->__getTypes()); echo "</pre>";
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class) has an explanation about how to access any available SOAP function.